# Details View Insert/update data through Coding

Tags: c#, asp.net, detailsview, insert-update

I'm trying to insert or update data into a database from detailsview through coding. Without giving a datasource to details view, because it is very easy. I want to do it programmatically.

As I said I didn't give the datasource directly. I did it on page load.

```
static string conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AptechConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conn);

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DetailsView1.AutoGenerateInsertButton = true;
    DetailsView1.AutoGenerateEditButton = true;
    DetailsView1.AutoGenerateDeleteButton = true;
    Data_Bind();
}

public void Data_Bind()
{
    string query = "select * from students";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);

    DetailsView1.DataSource = dt;
    DetailsView1.DataBind();
    ViewState["Data"] = dt;
}
```

I tried to do like we did in gridview

```
protected void DetailsView1_ItemInserting(object sender, DetailsViewInsertEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        id = (TextBox)DetailsView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].FindControl("TextBox1");
        name = (TextBox)DetailsView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].FindControl("TextBox2");
        batch = (TextBox)DetailsView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].FindControl("TextBox3");
        enrolled = (TextBox)DetailsView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].FindControl("TextBox4");
        teacher = (TextBox)DetailsView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].FindControl("TextBox5");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Label1.Text = ex.Message;
        Label1.Visible = true;
    }
}

protected void DetailsView1_ItemCommand(object sender, DetailsViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.CommandName.ToString())
    {
        case "New":
            DetailsView1.ChangeMode(DetailsViewMode.Insert);
            Data_Bind();
            break;
    }
}
```

But, when I click Edit or insert link button it gives me this error

> The DetailsView 'DetailsView1' fired event ModeChanging which wasn't handled."

What I'm missing?

Comment: Can you show the Markup portion of Your DetailsView

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `ModeChanging` event handler:

```
protected void DetailsView1_ModeChanging(object sender, DetailsViewModeEventArgs e)
{
    DetailsView1.ChangeMode(e.NewMode);
    Data_Bind();
}
```